# Javascript: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0') which assigning value to object

Tags: javascript, object

I want to assign values to an object which looks like:

```
test_data = {
 projectTitle: 'Test',
 source: 'home',
 destination: 'office',
 variables: {
    [
      speed: 20,
      velocity: 30
    ],
    [
      speed: 10,
      velocity: 20
    ],
 }
}
```

This is my code:

```
test_data: any = {}

test_data.projectTitle = (document.getElementById("project_title") as HTMLInputElement).value;
test_data.source = (document.getElementById("source") as HTMLInputElement).value;
test_data.destination = (document.getElementById("destination") as HTMLInputElement).value;

for (let i=0;i<2;i++) {
   test_data.variables[i].speed = (document.getElementById("speed_"+i) as HTMLInputElement).value;
   test_data.variables[i].velocity = (document.getElementById("velocity_"+i) as HTMLInputElement).value;
}
```

I am getting the error:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
```

How do i fix this?

Comment: `test_data.variables` is not array, it is object.  

`variables: {
    [
      speed: 20,
      velocity: 30
    ],
    [
      speed: 10,
      velocity: 20
    ],
 }`

its not valid btw.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the structure of the `variables` property, it seems that `speed` and `velocity` should be properties of an object too. You put those inside an array though.

So I'd recommend turning the variables object into an array and wrap the elements inside objects.

For example:

```js
let test_data = {
 projectTitle: 'Test',
 source: 'home',
 destination: 'office',
 variables: [
    {
      speed: 20,
      velocity: 30
    },
    {
      speed: 10,
      velocity: 20
    },
 ]
}

for (let i=0;i<2;i++) {
  console.log(test_data.variables[i].speed);
   console.log(test_data.variables[i].velocity);
}
```

Comment: I have tried doing that, I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Then I'd recommend posting a code snippet that clearly shows the issue you're having.